# Installing knative on existing kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, knative, kind

I have an existing kind k8s cluster with a bunch of running services and `nginx-ingress` setup and I would like to add knative to it.

Is there a way of doing this with `nginx-ingress`, seems like networking for knative is a bit more complex than a normal service installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knative needs more capabilities out of the HTTP routing layer than are exposed via the Kubernetes Ingress resource. (Percentage splits and header rewrite are two of the big ones.)

Unfortunately, so one has written an adapter from Knative's "KIngress" implementation to the `nginx` ingress. In the future, the [gateway API (aka "Ingress V2")](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/) may provide these capabilities; in the meantime, you'll need to install one of the other network adapters and ingress implementations. Kourier provides the smallest implementation, while Contour also provides an Ingress implementation if you want to switch from `nginx` entirely.